# A graph-coloring problem where only some of the edges should be bichromatic

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, terminology, coloring

In a standard graph-coloring problem, it is required that all edges will be bichromatic (i.e., all edges should be connected to two vertices with different colors). What is a term, and some basic references, for a graph-coloring problem in which only a fraction of the edges should satisfy this condition? For example, at least $\frac23$ or at least $\frac12$?

I looked for "fractional coloring" but, apparently, it is a completely different problem.

Comment: "`Partial proper colouring`", maybe?

Comment: what does bichromatic mean?

Comment: @mathnoob I added an explanation

Comment: @EdOverflow I found this expression here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.06704.pdf If I understand correctly, it refers to coloring in which only some of the vertices are colored, while others are not colored at all.

Comment: @erel-segal-halevi, yes, although the bichromatic property still holds for those that are coloured. I think the only downside to the term I suggested is that it implies the remaining vertices are not coloured at all (or not necessarily coloured). Maybe you could combine the terms `proper colouring` and `subgraphs` to describe what you are after above. I would need to look into this a bit more before I can suggest a more concrete term.

Comment: @EdOverflow The motivation is this fair division problem: https://arxiv.org/abs/1709.02564 . There, "coloring" corresponds (roughly) to an allocation that is fair for all members in both groups, and "partial coloring" corresponds to an allocation that is fair for at least half (or another fraction) of the members in each group.

Answer (score 2):

A colouring without the condition that edges be bicromatic is called by different names such as **relaxed coloring**, **improper coloring** and **defective coloring**. (warning: the term defective coloring is more commonly used to mean a relaxed coloring with a restriction on maximum degree allowed in colour classes; relaxed coloring with this restriction is explored enough in the literature in both theoretical interest and applications)

What you want is a relaxed coloring with a fraction of edges coloured properly. I remember seeing something similar to this on a paper on .... defective colouring(?), but quite don't remember the source.

I thought this could help someone interested to further explore.